# SwiftUI .overlay() causing data to be displayed incorrectly

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm working on an app that calls an api and displays the data on 6 different cards. In the card view the data displays correctly. Once I place that view into another using .overlay() the UI is perfect but the data on each card is the same. Without .overlay() the data is correct but the UI is wrong. I've tried changing my ViewModel variable in the views to @EnvironmentObject, @StateObject, & @ObservedObject with no luck. I can't figure out if this is a bug or I am missing something. Any help is greatly appreciated.

This view displays data correctly:

```
import SwiftUI

struct TopActivityCardView: View {
   // @EnvironmentObject var vm: ViewModel
      @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()
       var timePeriod = ""
    
       var body: some View {
      
        ZStack {
        ScrollView{
            ForEach(vm.fetch(), id: \.title) { item in
               RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
                .foregroundColor(Color.darkBlue)
            .frame(height: 120, alignment: .center)
            .padding(.top, 80)
            .overlay(

                ActivityTitleView(activityTitle: item.title)
            ).overlay(
                ActivityHoursView(workHours: item.timeframes.weekly.current)
            ).overlay(
                ActivityEllipisView()
            ).overlay(
                TimePeriodView(timePeriod: "Last Week", weeklyHrs: 
                item.timeframes.weekly.previous)
              )
            }
            
          }
            
        }

     }
}
    


struct TopActivityCardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TopActivityCardView()
            .environmentObject(ViewModel())
    }
}
```

This view is where the problem occurs:

```
import SwiftUI


struct RectCardView: View {

    var colorArray: [(colorName: Color, imageName: String)] = [(Color.work, "icon-work"), 
    (Color.play, "icon-play"), (Color.study, "icon-study"), (Color.exercise, "icon- 
    exercise"), (Color.social, "icon-social"), (Color.selfCare, "icon-self-care")]
    
    // @StateObject var vm = ViewModel()

    @ObservedObject var vm = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {

            ZStack{

            ScrollView{

                ForEach(colorArray, id: \.imageName) { colorName, imageName in

                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)

                        .foregroundColor(colorName)

                        .frame(height: 110, alignment: .center)

                        .overlay(

                            Image(imageName)

                                .brightness(-0.2)

                                .frame(width: 60, height: 20, alignment: .topLeading)

                                .offset(x: 103, y: -60)
                            
                        ).clipped()
                    
                    /// If I take .overlay() off the cards display correct data but UI is 
                         not correct.
                    ///  With overlay UI is correct but data on cards is all the same.
                    
                        .overlay{

                            TopActivityCardView()

                                .padding(.top, -40)
                            
                        }
                        .padding(.top, 20)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct RectCardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {`enter code here`
        RectCardView()
            .environmentObject(ViewModel())
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you make a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: The problem is that I am not getting any errors. It is just the data isn't displayed correctly on the card when used with .overlay(). Without .overlay() the data on the cards is correct but the UI is bad. I've posted all the code pertaining to the question, but if you want to check out my GitHub, you can find the project under

Comment: RachelRadford21/FEMTimeTrackingDashboard

Comment: Ok I think I know why — posting the answer now.

Answer (score 1):

In TopActivityCardView, you are making a *new* view model (`@StateObject var vm = ViewModel()`).

It isn't using the same view model as `RectCardView`, so the data is different.

You could pass the view into TopActivityCardView by using an environment object:

```swift
// code…
struct TopActivityCardView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var vm: ViewModel
    // more code…
}
```

```swift
.overlay{
    TopActivityCardView()
        .environmentObject(vm)
        .padding(.top, -40)                      
}
```

Comment: I did try this before & then again now, it doesn't work. It's so confusing!!

Comment: Maybe try putting breakpoints into the code to see what gets returned from `vm.fetch()` (in TopActivityCardView)?

Comment: Ok, I will try that. I also tried using .task{ vm.fetch() } in TopActivityCardView, but that didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: This was exactly my problem, and the solution was the perfect fix, so maybe it's worth another try to follow it?  Good luck!